Is there 'nbd-server stop/reload'
How do I stop or reload the nbd-server?
Once I change the config at /etc/nbd-server/config, then what?
I can't find any answers...

man nbd-server ... nothing
NetworkBlockDevice Git page... nothing
Ubuntu docs... nothing

The only thing I can use is:

killall nbd-server
kill $(pgrep nbd-server)

Shouldn't there be something like?

nbd-server reload
nbd-server stop

